# trying to convert a float into a decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x

so here is the formula,
3.14 = 3*10^0+1*10^-1+4*10^-2=3.14

but I am using the following python script and it keeps calculated the result of 3.55, can anyone help on this?

```
n=0
m='3.14'.split('.')
for i in m:
    if i == m[0]:
        f= (int(i,base=10))
    else:
        for x in i:
            for v in range(len(i)):
                    n+=10**(-v-1)*int(x)
print (float(f+n))
```

Comment: the title says float to decimal but your example shows string to float...what are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last two loops, loop two time over the same thing, i.e. you do 1*10^-1 + 4*10^-1 + 1*10^-2 + 4*10^-2, leading to the .55.

You should write:

```
n=0
m='3.14'.split('.')
for i in m:
    if i == m[0]:
        f= (int(i,base=10))
    else:
        v=0
        for x in i:
          n+=10**(-v-1)*int(x)
          v=v+1
print (float(f+n))
```

But you have buil-in functions to do all of that for you

Comment: thanks so much!may I ask what built-in functions can I use?

Comment: As suggested above, just `float("3.14")`, but I found interesting for you to also see what was wrong in you code

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that u don't try to cast the value  of m into float ;instead, you are trying to use split method which there is no sensible use of it here,
instead of that, try to cast m into float and then use your formula and for loop

> in case you don't know how to cast
>   `m = float('3.14')`